# SQL with conditional logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a query that currently returns a table of 1s and 0s like the following

```
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

However, I would like to modify my query so that for rows with multiple 1s, we only keep the first 1 in the row.  For example, I want to convert (1 1 1) to (1 0 0), (0 1 1) to (0 1 0), and so forth.  It seems like IF logic would be a last resort.

What would you all recommend? Could I do a case statement where the value in one column depends on another columns value?

In other words, "COLUMN 2 = CASE WHEN COLUMN 1 = 1 and COLUMN 2 = 1, then 0...etc?"

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 2):

For three columns, the logic is:

```
select col1,
       (case when col1 = 1 then 0 else col2 end) as col2,
       (case when col1 = 1 or col2 = 1 then 0 else col3 end) as col3
from query q
```

If you had more columns, I would take a different approach:

```
select col1,
       (case when firstOne < 2 then 0 else col2 end) as col2,
       (case when firstOne < 3 then 0 else col3 end) as col3,
       (case when firstOne < 4 then 0 else col4 end) as col4,
       . . .
from (select q.*,
             (case when col1 = 1 then 1
                   when col2 = 1 then 2
                   when col3 = 1 then 3
                   . . .
              end) as FirstOne
      from query q
     ) q
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to conditional constructs, you could do something like:

```
select a, b * (1-a) as [b'], c * (1-b) * (1-a) as [c'] 
from your_table
```

This does depend on columns a, b and c each being allowed the values 0 and 1 only.

(Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/014de/108).)